# Multi-Threading - Code Skipping

Tags: c#

I have a problem on the

```
public async Task<bool> CreateNewClient(Client newClient) {
    bool isCreated = false;

    if (newClient != null) {

        Client client = await GetClientByIdAsync(newClient.Id);

        if (client == null) {
            _db.ClientRepository.Add(newClient);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            var model = new RegisterCustomerModel() {
                Username = client.Id,
                Password = password
            };


            await RegisterToAuthorizeSystem(client.Id);
            isCreated = true;
        }
    }

    return isCreated;
}
```

After the checking on debug the on line 9 it stop working and `return true` while the next statements are not executed. After `SaveChangesAsync()` it goes on create the `model` and stops. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Which line is line 9?

Comment: It's not terribly easy to understand your description. It doesn't help that there's a lot of code you're referring to which isn't provided at all. Could you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Can you include the code calling CreateNewClient() ?

Comment: Please specify the line of code, rather than line numbers - while most IDEs may have them, Stack Overflow does not, and it's tedious needing to count lines.

Comment: Line 9 is not "await _db.SaveChangesAsync();" by any chance is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `await` an asynchronous method (and it actually executes asynchronously), the result is an immediate `return`. That's how `await` works - and that's why it returns `Task<bool>` instead of just `bool` - you're not being given the value, just a promise of the value sometime in the future. Maybe.

This makes debugging a bit trickier, of course. When you just step line-by-line in a debugger, you're actually following the executing thread, not the executing *task*. The rest of the method is executed later, when the asynchronous operation actually completes - but by that point, the caller thread is either already gone, or it's doing something different. If you actually put a breakpoint on the line after `await _db.SaveChangesAsync();`, it will be hit as usual (unless the operation throws an exception, of course).

Your problem is most likely with the code that *calls* your asynchronous method - in particular, at some point, you forget to do `await SomeAsync()` instead of `SomeAsync()`. This completely untangles the chain of asynchronous operations, and you lose any unhandled exceptions as well as the return value.

Answer (score -1):

Best guess is there's an exception being thrown here because your using client.Id in the model assignment instead of the newClient you just saved. The client is still null at that point.